# How to troubleshoot or debug a MakeTable query Access

Tags: ms-access

A maketable query in an Access database named v3.0 randomly stopped working sometime after I added some VBA code that had nothing to do with the query. My boss is chewing me out. I got v3.1 working with no edits despite my macro being there . V3.1 works perfectly fine but for some reason my boss is still concerned over v3.0

My problem is this. I cant run the maketable without it freezing BUT IT ALSO FREEZES WHEN I TRY TO OPEN IT IN DESIGN VIEW. Would anything cause a query to stop working suddenly like this?

Comment: What other tables does the make-table query reference?  Are any of them linked tables?  Perhaps shared the SQL.   If you can't get into the design view without it freezing, then go to Visual Basic Immediate pane and type `Debug.Print CurrentDB.QueryDefs("QueryName").SQL`  Also, describe in more detail what "stopped working" means.  Are you executing the query manually, or in VBA code, or in a macro?  Any errors?

Comment: Manually, and in macro it fails/freezes. It is possible it does reference linked tables. I run a batch of queries in the macro but it always freezes on that one. Ill enter the code in the pane as you suggested when i get in tomorrow. What couls i expect to see

Comment: And say the debug did return sometime obviously wrong. How would i change it

Comment: I hesitate to guess, but if it references linked tables, it could be that the linked source (other database, file?) has been changed or is otherwise inaccessible.  The linked table could perhaps need to be updated.  Strange that it's not giving you a error, but just a guess.  And the debug statement won't necessarily reveal anything obviously wrong... that suggestion is just to get more information.  Without more details about the query and tables it references, it's all just wild guessing.

Comment: Id agree with you there. Thanks for your help

Comment: One more question though 3.1 and 3 both probably use the same linked tables....

Comment: Then perhaps something was changed in the VB code, even accidentally?  Are you certain the query doesn't call any VB code?  The SQL statement will reveal that.